# Tornado stopped running on AWS immediately after I terminate my remote session

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, tornado

I'm using SSH to remotely launch Tornado on Amazon Web Service. It works fine when I launch it by:

python startTornado.py

However, after my SSH session times out or terminated, the Tornado server is also stopped immediately, so I can't access the webpage anymore. I did quite some search but couldn't find an answer on Google.

How can I keep Tornado and the site running after my SSH session terminated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process will shut down when you logout if it's running in the foreground or if it tries to write to stdout and the terminal it's outputting to no longer exists. Try starting the server with

```
nohup python startTornado.py &
```

The nohup command redirects output to a file, and the & at the end runs the command in the background. Alternatively, you can use the screen utility which allows you to detach a terminal and reattach it in a different ssh session (see the screen man page for details).

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this works very well. I think the trouble will come up if the output file is filled with errors though.

Answer (score 3):

While all the above solutions solve the immediate problem, what you might really need to run such processes in production, control them (start/restart/stop) is [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). It is python based and its more useful when you have to run multiple instances of tornado behind nginx.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `nohup` as Kevin has mentioned, you can also use [`disown`](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch23_11.htm) command if you are using bash:

```
disown <job-id>
```

Comment: Thanks Kay. From the document of disown, seems it won't need an output file right? That will resolve the problem of too many error logs.

Comment: @lichen19853 No problem :) I am not sure what you mean, `disown` takes one argument which is the id of the job.